# How to show UIViewController properly?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I need to show a view controller and have this current code:

```
    SavedFiles *savedFilesVC = [[[SavedFiles alloc] init] autorelease];
    [self presentModalViewController:savedFilesVC animated:YES];
```

Although it gets this error:

```
2011-09-12 18:38:45.808 iDHSB[248:707] -[iDHSB_MobileAppDelegate presentModalViewController:animated:]: unrecognized selector     
sent to instance 0x1bb880
2011-09-12 18:38:45.825 iDHSB[248:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-   
[iDHSB_MobileAppDelegate presentModalViewController:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1bb880'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x3583064f __exceptionPreprocess + 114
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x36583c5d objc_exception_throw + 24
2   CoreFoundation                      0x358341bf -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 102
3   CoreFoundation                      0x35833649 ___forwarding___ + 508
4   CoreFoundation                      0x357aa180 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 48
5   iDHSB                               0x00007671 -[iDHSB_MobileAppDelegate actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:] + 140
6   UIKit                               0x3203c03d -[UIActionSheet(Private) _buttonClicked:] + 192
7   CoreFoundation                      0x357a0571 -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 24
8   UIKit                               0x31f39ec9 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 84
9   UIKit                               0x31f39e69 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 32
10  UIKit                               0x31f39e3b -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 38
11  UIKit                               0x31f39b8d -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 356
12  UIKit                               0x31f3a423 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 342
13  UIKit                               0x31f38bf5 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 368
14  UIKit                               0x31f3856f -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 262
15  UIKit                               0x31f21313 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 298
16  UIKit                               0x31f20c53 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5090
17  GraphicsServices                    0x31df7e77 PurpleEventCallback + 666
18  CoreFoundation                      0x35807a97 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 26
19  CoreFoundation                      0x3580983f __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 166
20  CoreFoundation                      0x3580a60d __CFRunLoopRun + 520
21  CoreFoundation                      0x3579aec3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
22  CoreFoundation                      0x3579adcb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 58
23  GraphicsServices                    0x31df741f GSEventRunModal + 114
24  GraphicsServices                    0x31df74cb GSEventRun + 62
25  UIKit                               0x31f4bd69 -[UIApplication _run] + 404
26  UIKit                               0x31f49807 UIApplicationMain + 670
27  iDHSB                               0x0000232d main + 48
28  iDHSB                               0x000022f8 start + 40
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
[Switching to process 11779 thread 0x0]
```

Why is this happening?

What do I need to do?

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like this in your AppDelegate to load the first ViewController:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Add the navigation controller's view to the window and display

    self.window.rootViewController = myController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Loading and initializing the view controller happens (typically) in the MainWindow.xib file.  You cannot call presentModalViewController from an AppDelegate and you cannot just init your controller, you need initFromNib in most cases..

Comment: what should I put here: "myController"?

Comment: What are you working from?  If you use the xCode provided templates to start your app, all of this is done for you.

Comment: I am working from  an appdelegate but want to show a UIViewController

Comment: I mean are you working in xCode?  If you setup your project correctly in xCode from the start you shouldn't have to do any of this initial view setup.

Comment: I just set it up as a single view app and then added a viewcontroller after.

Comment: A single view app should come with an xCode provided view controller.  You should put your code for your first view in there.  If you are going to display another view after that, you should do it from within the first viewController and not from the appDelegate.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

or

```
[self.view addsubview.viewcontroller.view];
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `presentModalViewController:animated:` directly from an AppDelegate. It must be presented from an instance of `UIViewController`. This is the cause of the error.

Comment: it isn't, it's a view controller I believe as that's what I set it as :S

Comment: my current file (iDHSB_MobileAppDelegate) is a AppDelegate file which is then needing to call a UIViewController file. Would this make a difference?

Comment: Where are these lines of code? This will tell you what `self` is. Try instead to set a `rootViewController` and then present a modal view from that.

Comment: these lines of code are in a UIActionSheet button index. How would I do that? Thanks! :)

Comment: @James: No what function, what **file**. Read my answer again. An AppDelegate does not respond to `presentModalViewController:animated:`. That method is for instances of `UIViewController`.

Comment: yes I know, the file I wanted to show is a UIViewController but the file where the code to show it is in, is a AppDelegate.

Answer (score 1):

```
[[iDHSB_MobileAppDelegate mainViewController] presentModalViewController:savedFilesVC  animated:YES]
```

**you need to create a UIViewController say for ex mainViewController and connect it into xib.**

Comment: didn't work unfortunately, got an NSException saying that mainViewController wasn't declared...

Comment: you need to define as an IBOutLet UIViewController in your header file and connect it to xib.

Comment: You add a control UIViewController in to your MainWindow.xib and connect it to your IBOutlet UIViewController* mainViewController which you define in your appDelegate header file.